# Scripts used by `jockey-common`

Tags: python, scripts, jockey

Is it possible to make a script that basically does the same thing as `jockey-common`? i.e. An script to find any hardware that requires proprietary drivers and install them.

**EDIT** As Oli mentioned, the scripts are already present in Ubuntu, if any of you are already aware as to which script corresponds to which options listed in `jockey-text --help` and how to use them, please answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I know what you want to achieve but `jockey-text` will let you detect and install drivers from the command line.

It has various arguments where you'd be able to parse the output and feed them back into it via a script. Just look at `jockey-text --help`

If you need to really play around with *how* it works, it's all Python (with a light dusting of dbus) so you're free to just dive in and hack around with whatever you want.

You can find the scripts in `/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/jockey/` (this path will change in future Ubuntu versions when there's a different Python version being used) and you can see how `jockey-text` interfaces with this in its own script here: `/usr/bin/jockey-text`.

I'd suggest inheriting `jockey.ui.AbstractUI` like `jockey-text` does and working it from there. It's not a simple application though. It's going to take a bit of time to figure out what's actually happening inside that class before you can meaningfully use it.

Comment: Yes, I'm already aware of it - `jockey-text` and `jockey-gtk` (Additional Drivers) are there because of `jockey-common`. What I'm looking for is a script that is an alternative solution to let me detect and install restricted drivers.

Comment: Have a look at `/usr/bin/jockey-text` and you'll see it's just a wrapper around other Python scripts in `/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/jockey/`. You're free to pull those apart and dig in.

Comment: I was hoping it'd be something like that and thinking to take a peek into the source code (even though I don't really know any programming), so thanks for the pointer! I'll accept this answer if I can get them to work.

Comment: By different Python version, do you mean the scripts will be upgraded to use Python 3? (Python three isn't consistent with older versions, as far as I know)

Comment: @Oxwivi It's a class in  `/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/jockey/ui.py`